# Why is $T(Y)\subset Y$ where $Y=X\setminus \bigcup_{n\geq 0} T^{-n}(U)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $T:X\rightarrow X$ be continuous. Let $U\subset X$ be open and nonempty and define $$Y=X\setminus \bigcup_{n\geq 0} T^{-n}(U)$$I want to show that $T(Y)\subset Y$.

Somehow I am really confused since it does not work. I thought about taking $x\in T(Y)$ i.e. $T^{-1}(x)\in X\setminus \bigcup_{n\geq 0} T^{-n}(U)$. Then I wanted to assume by contradiction that there is $n\geq 0$ s.t. $T^{-1}(x)\in T^{-n}(U)$ i.e. $T^{n-1}(x)\subset U$.But I don't see how I can find a contradiction?

Can maybe someone help me futher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by definition of the set $Y$ for any $y\in X$ we have
$$
y\in Y\Leftrightarrow y\notin\bigcup_{n\geq 0}T^{-n}(U)\Leftrightarrow\forall n\geq 0:T^n(y)\notin U.
$$
Take any $y\in Y$. Can you see now why we have $T(y)\in Y$ and why does this imply the required statement?

Comment: Ah yes I think so because if we pick $n\geq 0$ arbitrary then for all $y\in Y$ $$T^n(Ty)=T^{n+1}(y)\not \in U$$ this is equivalent to say that $T(y)\in Y$. So in particular $y\subset T^{-1}(Y)$ and since this holds for all $y$ we deduce $Y\subset T^{-1}(Y)\Leftrightarrow T(Y)\subset Y$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.